# WCF Interface implementation

Tags: c#, wcf, interface, implementation

Understand that English isn't everyone's first language so be lenient of bad spelling and grammar I am working on a C#/WCF project.

I need to use my methods contain in ClassLibrary1 through WCF service web.

Here is the code of my test solution.

```
using WcfService1;

namespace ClassLibrary1
{
    public class Class1 : IService1
    {
        public string Hello(string who)
        {
            return "Hello " + who + " from classlibrary1 NOT FROM wcfservice1";
        }
    }
}
```

And the WcfService1 :

```
 namespace WcfService1
{
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IService1
    {
        [OperationContract]
        string Hello(string who);
    }
}  



namespace WcfService1
{
    public class Service1 : IService1
    {
        public string Hello(string who)
        {
            return "Hello " + who + " from wcfservice1";
        }
    }
}
```

This works pretty good, but this is not my aim. In my real solution, I have got like 500+ methods, and I would like to implement the IService1.cs as above.

But I dont want to copy all my methods in the Service1.svc from WcfService1.

I dont know if it's possible to use WcfService1.IService1 to implement ClassLibrary1.Class1 and use it through WCF ?

I would like when I'm running Client Test WCF that I can use my method Hello(string) and return : Hello + who + from classlibrary1 NOT FROM wcfservice1.

I'm looking for a solution but can't find it :/

Comment: Do they implement the same `IService1` interface, or are there two interfaces with this name?

Comment: Can you add an image of what your solution tree looks like? I think what you need to do is add a reference to ClassLibrary1 in your WCF Service project. Then in your .svc file you can specify the code behind as your ClassLibrary1.cs file

Comment: @TimS. Yes they implement the same IService1. How can I open my .svc file to view the code behing ? I'm totally lost !

Comment: I found how to change it ! Now my Service1.svc looks like : <%@ ServiceHost Language="C#" Debug="true" Service="ClassLibrary1.Class1" CodeBehind="Service1.svc.cs" %>
But there is still an error WcfService1.Service1 does not implement interface member WcfService1.IService1.Hello(string). I delete all the method in my Service1 because normally I wont need it ! Need some helps :/

Comment: @Shrimp you should remove the `CodeBehind`, `Language`, and `Debug` tags. They aren't needed with how you have your class defined. And you can delete the Service1.svc.cs file.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't define a `WcfService1.Service1` class. Just use the `ClassLibrary1.Class1` class. Reference `ClassLibrary1`'s project from `WcfService1`'s project and change your web.config and .svc files as necessary to use `Class1`.  E.g. you might have an .svc file that is currently:

```
<%@ ServiceHost Service="WcfService1.Service1" %>
```

Change it to

```
<%@ ServiceHost Service="ClassLibrary1.Class1" %>
```

And similarly in your web.config:

```
  <service name="WcfService1.Service1"> <!-- becomes... -->
  <service name="ClassLibrary1.Class1">
```

Comment: In my web.config, I dont have any <service name>, and where should I change first tip <%@ ServiceHost Service%> ? I can't change my .svc ? Actually in my .svc there is only my method Hello from wcfservice1. Or maybe should I do something else in my "code behind" ? How can I see it ? I'm totally lost!

Comment: @Shrimp if you don't see anything about it in your web.config, don't worry about it for now. Just try to get the rest in order and try to test the service - if it works, great, and if it doesn't, then hopefully you'll have a clue as to what is still referring to the old class, or otherwise incorrect.